# What variable parameters should be considered to predict solar output at a particular location

Tags: machine-learning, weather-api, solar

I am trying out a machine learning regression algorithm to predict the output or yield of a solar panel at a particular location defined by the latitude and longitude. As per what I have read, there are parameters like irradiance, ambient temperature, wind speed etc. which impact the output on a given day and time. Does anyone know which are the minimum set of parameters which should be considered to predict the solar yield? They can be weather parameters or specification parameters of the panels also. Also is there any online api which will give the required parameters hourly, daily, yearly for a particular latitude/longitude